# Connecting/Querying Data Access Database in C# using DBLINQ

Tags: c#, linq, ms-access, database-connection, dblinq

Bear with me, I'm new to databases.

I have an Access database, "Database.accdb". It's located on my local computer: "C:\Users\MyUserName\Documents\Database.accdb". I have a C# program trying to establish a connection with this database.

I attempt to create a class derived from DbLinq Datacontext.

```
namespace DatabaseTest.Database
{

    public partial class DatabaseTestDataContext : DataContext
    {

        public DatabaseTestDataContext()
        : base(@"C:\Users\MyUserName\Documents\Database.accdb")
        { }

        #region Tables
        public Table<Tables.TestTable> TestTable { get { return GetTable<Tables.TestTable>(); } }
        #endregion

    }
}
```

I attempt to query the database like this:

```
var TTDB = new DatabaseTest.Database.DatabaseTestDataContext();
var collection = from x in TTDB.TestTable
                 where x.TestID == "A003"
                 select x;
foreach (var item in collection)
{
    MessageBox.Show(item.Part);
}
```

Running this code results in the following error:

> System.ArgumentException: 'Unable to load the `DbLinq.SqlServer' DbLinq vendor within assembly 'SqlServer.dll'.'
>
> Inner Exception
>   FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'DbLinq.SqlServer' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Basically, I am not completely sure how to connect to an Access Database (located on my personal computer) using the DBLINQ DataContext. Perhaps I am simply missing a reference? Any suggestions?

Comment: I'm not familiar with DbLinq but it looks like it does not support MS Access or you need to configure it so it does not think you are using MSSQL Server. Do you need to use MS Access? It is really horrible as a stand alone database engine when you have Sqlite or SQL Express and local db available.